# Retrieve Windows Experience Rating

Tags: c#, rating

I'm looking to retrieve a machine's windows experience rating in C#.  If possible I would also like to retrieve the numbers for each component (Graphics, RAM etc.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time the user goes through control panel to calculate the Windows Experience Rating, the system creates a new file in `%Windows%\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\`

You need to find the most recent file (they are named with the most significant date first, so finding the latest file is trivial).

These files are xml files and are easy to parse with XmlReader or other xml parser.

The section you are interested in is `WinSAT\WinSPR` and contains all the scores in a single section. E.g.

```
<WinSAT>
    <WinSPR>
        <SystemScore>3.7</SystemScore> 
        <MemoryScore>5.9</MemoryScore> 
        <CpuScore>5.2</CpuScore> 
        <CPUSubAggScore>5.1</CPUSubAggScore> 
        <VideoEncodeScore>5.3</VideoEncodeScore> 
        <GraphicsScore>3.9</GraphicsScore> 
        <GamingScore>3.7</GamingScore> 
        <DiskScore>5.2</DiskScore> 
    </WinSPR>
...
```

Comment: As Microsoft removed the Windows Experience Index page from Control Panel in Windows 8 onwards, you'll first need to generate a new file in the data store. See here for more info: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CalculateYourWEIWindowsExperienceIndexUnderWindows81.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Same with LINQ:

```
var dirName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%WinDir%\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\");
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
var file = dirInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*Formal.Assessment*.xml")
    .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTime)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (file == null)
    throw new FileNotFoundException("WEI assessment xml not found");

var doc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);

Console.WriteLine("Processor: " + doc.Descendants("CpuScore").First().Value);
Console.WriteLine("Memory (RAM): " + doc.Descendants("MemoryScore").First().Value);
Console.WriteLine("Graphics: " + doc.Descendants("GraphicsScore").First().Value);
Console.WriteLine("Gaming graphics: " + doc.Descendants("GamingScore").First().Value);
Console.WriteLine("Primary hard disk: " + doc.Descendants("DiskScore").First().Value);
Console.WriteLine("Base score: " + doc.Descendants("SystemScore").First().Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1456.htm) is a snippet for VB.NET. Converted to C# (using [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/), I haven't actually tested the code yet, though it looks to be fine).

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the base score of a computer running Windows Vista or higher.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The String Representation of Score, or False.</returns>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public string GetBaseScore()
{
    // Check if the computer has a \WinSAT dir.
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Windows\\Performance\\WinSAT\\DataStore"))
    { 
        // Our method to get the most recently updated score.
        // Because the program makes a new XML file on every update of the score,
        // we need to calculate the most recent, just incase the owner has upgraded.
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo Dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows\\Performance\\WinSAT\\DataStore");
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fileDir = null;
        System.IO.FileInfo fileMostRecent = default(IO.FileInfo);
        System.DateTime LastAccessTime = default(System.DateTime);
        string LastAccessPath = string.Empty;
        fileDir = Dir.GetFiles;

        // Loop through the files in the \WinSAT dir to find the newest one.
        foreach (var fileMostRecent in fileDir)
        {
            if (fileMostRecent.LastAccessTime >= LastAccessTime)
            {
                LastAccessTime = fileMostRecent.LastAccessTime;
                LastAccessPath = fileMostRecent.FullName;
            }
        }

        // Create an XmlTextReader instance.
        System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReadScore = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(LastAccessPath);

        // Disable whitespace handling so we don't read over them
        xmlReadScore.WhitespaceHandling = System.Xml.WhitespaceHandling.None;

        // We need to get to the 25th tag, "WinSPR".
        for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
        {
            xmlReadScore.Read();
        }

        // Create a string variable, so we can clean up without any mishaps.
        string SystemScore = xmlReadScore.ReadElementString("SystemScore");

        // Clean up.
        xmlReadScore.Close();

        return SystemScore;
    }

    // Unsuccessful.
    return false;
}
```

I guess it only returns the overall rating, but hopefully it should get you started at least. It may only be a matter of changing a filename/parameter to get the individual ratings.