# Programmatically get the Windows Experience Index value

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve Windows Experience Rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479435/retrieve-windows-experience-rating)

Using .NET, is there a way to programmatically query the present value of the Windows Experience Index?

Comment: See [this][1] StackOverflow answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479435/retrieve-windows-experience-rating

Comment: Matthew, please post this as an answer so I can mark it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, I did, but SO transformed it due to it being a "Trivial answer"... will try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully the StackOverflow engine won't transform this into an autocomment.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479435/retrieve-windows-experience-rating) Stack Overflow answer:

Answer (score 2):

Another option is use the [WinSAT Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737394%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this task, check the  [`IProvideWinSATResultsInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969188%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface for more info and the WMI Class [`Win32_WinSAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969204%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Check this sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_WinSAT");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CPUScore: {0}", queryObj["CPUScore"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("D3DScore: {0}", queryObj["D3DScore"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("DiskScore: {0}", queryObj["DiskScore"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("GraphicsScore: {0}", queryObj["GraphicsScore"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("MemoryScore: {0}", queryObj["MemoryScore"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("TimeTaken: {0}", queryObj["TimeTaken"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("WinSATAssessmentState: {0}", queryObj["WinSATAssessmentState"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("WinSPRLevel: {0}", queryObj["WinSPRLevel"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In 64bit environment, if the sample is compiled with /platform:x86, results are always zero and WinSATAssessmentState is 3.